# Python remove negative number entries/rows from csv

Tags: python, linux, csv, awk, matplotlib

I have a ever growing csv file that looks like:

```
143100, 2012-05-21 09:52:54.165852
125820, 2012-05-21 09:53:54.666780
109260, 2012-05-21 09:54:55.144712
116340, 2012-05-21 09:55:55.642197
125640, 2012-05-21 09:56:56.094999
122820, 2012-05-21 09:57:56.546567
124770, 2012-05-21 09:58:57.046050
103830, 2012-05-21 09:59:57.497299
114120, 2012-05-21 10:00:58.000978
-31549410, 2012-05-21 10:01:58.063470
90390, 2012-05-21 10:02:58.108794
81690, 2012-05-21 10:03:58.161329
80940, 2012-05-21 10:04:58.227664
102180, 2012-05-21 10:05:58.289882
99750, 2012-05-21 10:06:58.322063
87000, 2012-05-21 10:07:58.391256
92160, 2012-05-21 10:08:58.442438
80130, 2012-05-21 10:09:58.506494
```

The negative numbers occur when the service that generates the file has an API connection failure. I'm already using matplotlib to graph the data, however the artificial negative numbers screw the graph greatly. I would like to locate all negative entries and remove the corresponding lines. At no point is a negative number actually representative of any real data.

In Bash I would do something like:

```
awk '{print $1}' original.csv | sed '/-/d' > new.csv
```

but that's messy and tends to be slow, and I don't really want to embed bash commands in my python graphing script if I can help it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

Here's the code I'm using to read/plot the data:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')                                          
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec                           
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                               
import matplotlib.dates as mdates                              
from pylab import *                                         

output_image_name='tpm.png'                   

data = csv2rec('counter.log', names=['packets', 'time'])   
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 5                              
rcParams['font.size'] = 8                                       

fig = plt.figure()                                              

plt.plot(data['packets'], data['time'])                      

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)                                       
ax.plot(data['time'], data['tweets'])                         
hours = mdates.HourLocator()                                    
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%D - %H:%M')                       
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)                               
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)                               

ax.grid()                                                

plt.ylabel("packets")                                         
plt.title("Packet Log: Packets Per Minute")         

fig.autofmt_xdate(bottom=0.2, rotation=90, ha='left')         

plt.savefig(output_image_name)
```

Comment: How is your python script reading the data? It could be as simple as skipping lines that begin with `-` in your loops, but you show no code.

Comment: That `awk '{print $1}'` is unnecessary, you could just use `sed '/-/d' original.csv > new.csv`

Comment: @wooble I've added the plotting code in response to your comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Python idiom would be to use a generator expression to filter the lines:

```
sys.stdout.writelines(line for line in sys.stdin if not line.startswith('-'))
```

Or in a processing context:

```
filtered = (line for line in sys.stdin if not line.startswith('-'))
for line in filtered:
    # ...
```

Comment: Isn't here another pair of round brackets () missing in the `writelines` argument in order to make the list comprehension create a generator?

Comment: @Jan: No, it's not a list comprehension, it's a generator expression. The pair of parens is unnecessary if it is the only argument to a function.

Comment: @Niklas B.  By itself it's probably not faster than sed, but since he'll already be iterating in Python, it would make sense to filter there as well.

Comment: I'm using csv2rec in my plot script: 
        data = csv2rec(counter.log, names=['packets', 'time'])
am I to deduce that it would look something like: 
filtered = (line for line in 'tpm_counter.log' if not line.startswith('-'))
for line in filtered:
        data = csv2rec(line, names=['packets', 'time'])

Comment: @secumind: If you are talking about matplotlib, then no, csv2rec takes a filename or file-like object, not a string. You could use [`stringio`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) for that as in `from cStringIO import StringIO; f = StringIO(''.join(filtered)); data = csv2rec(f, ...)` but that would require you to load the whole file into memory. The easiest solution would be to actually pre-process the file beforehand using sed or Python and write it to a new location (possibly on a RAM disk)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rewriting the files, I would filter the data on read, i.e. just before plotting.

Comment: This would be a good approach, especially because it allows you to hold on to potentially important information. No need to delete it from the file, just so you can plot it correctly.

Comment: @Jan-Philip I've added my plotting code, and I agree that that would be the ideal way, I'm just not sure how when using csv2rec to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This program opens your csv file, removes the lines starting with negative integers, and saves it to a different file. If you want, you can overwrite this on the same file with slight modification.

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    with open('data2.csv', 'w') as g:
        for row in f:
            if row[0] != '-':
                g.write(row)
```

Comment: This seems to be unnecessarily complex for the OP's purpose. Why are you splitting the rows up, only to join them together again at the end?

Comment: -1 for not using `csv` module, for reading entire file into memory, and for modifying a list you are iterating over (which is an error).  Also, the `with` statement has been out for some time and you do not use it.

Comment: @JoelCornett, fixed. That was stupid. I was looking for negative integers, I could just look for a minus sign.

Comment: @AbhranilDas: Better. `file` objects are already iterable. Instead of `read()`ing from the file, `split()`ting the file and then iterating through the lines, why don't you just do `for line in f:`. Also, you can open two files at the same time, and read from one directly into the other. :)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, fixed that list modifying thing. The other things I can't, because I don't know those things yet. Still pretty amateur at python.

Comment: @AbhranilDas: The `with` block implicitly `close()`s the file, even if an exception occurs within the block.

Comment: @JoelCornett, thanks a lot. I didn't know you could iterate over a file, or anything about `with` and `write`. Picked up a lot of things from this question :-)

Comment: You can also use `with open('data.csv', 'r') as f, open('data2.csv', 'w') as g:` to avoid the nesting